# Unknown Error when install Microsoft Machine Learning Server 9.4.7 and Microsoft R Client 3.5.2

Tags: r, azure-machine-learning-service, microsoft-r, microsoft-machine-learning-server

I want to install Microsoft Machine Learning Server 9.4.7 and Microsoft R Client 3.5.2, and I download the exe file from https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=Machine%20Learning%20Server%209.4.7%20for%20Windows&pgroup= and https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=R%20client&pgroup=.

I followed the instructions to install the software but failed. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/machine-learning-server/install/machine-learning-server-windows-install)

Log file for Microsoft Machine Learning Server

```
[4868:486C][2020-01-13T20:06:38]i001: Burn v3.10.1.2213, Windows v10.0 (Build 17763: Service Pack 0), path: K:\ServerSetup.exe
[4868:486C][2020-01-13T20:06:38]i000: Initializing string variable 'InstallFolder' to value '[ProgramFiles64Folder]Microsoft\ML Server'
[4868:486C][2020-01-13T20:06:38]i000: Initializing string variable 'CacheFolder' to value '[TempFolder]'
[4868:486C][2020-01-13T20:06:38]i000: Initializing string variable 'MediaFolder' to value '[TempFolder]'
[4868:486C][2020-01-13T20:06:38]i009: Command Line: ''
[4868:486C][2020-01-13T20:06:38]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'C:\Users\lzw\AppData\Local\Temp\Microsoft_Machine_Learning_Server_20200113200638.log'
[4868:486C][2020-01-13T20:06:38]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value 'K:\ServerSetup.exe'
[4868:486C][2020-01-13T20:06:38]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder' to value 'K:\'
[4868:486C][2020-01-13T20:06:38]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleName' to value 'Microsoft Machine Learning Server'
[4868:486C][2020-01-13T20:06:38]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleManufacturer' to value 'Microsoft'
[4868:486C][2020-01-13T20:06:38]i000: Loading managed bootstrapper application.
[4868:486C][2020-01-13T20:06:38]i000: Creating BA thread to run asynchronously.
[4868:486C][2020-01-13T20:06:43]i500: Shutting down, exit code: 0x0
[4868:486C][2020-01-13T20:06:43]i410: Variable: CacheFolder = C:\Users\lzw\AppData\Local\Temp\
[4868:486C][2020-01-13T20:06:43]i410: Variable: InstallFolder = C:\Program Files\Microsoft\ML Server
[4868:486C][2020-01-13T20:06:43]i410: Variable: MediaFolder = C:\Users\lzw\AppData\Local\Temp\
[4868:486C][2020-01-13T20:06:43]i410: Variable: ProgramFiles64Folder = C:\Program Files\
[4868:486C][2020-01-13T20:06:43]i410: Variable: TempFolder = C:\Users\lzw\AppData\Local\Temp\
[4868:486C][2020-01-13T20:06:43]i410: Variable: WixBundleAction = 5
[4868:486C][2020-01-13T20:06:43]i410: Variable: WixBundleElevated = 0
[4868:486C][2020-01-13T20:06:43]i410: Variable: WixBundleLog = C:\Users\lzw\AppData\Local\Temp\Microsoft_Machine_Learning_Server_20200113200638.log
[4868:486C][2020-01-13T20:06:43]i410: Variable: WixBundleManufacturer = Microsoft
[4868:486C][2020-01-13T20:06:43]i410: Variable: WixBundleName = Microsoft Machine Learning Server
[4868:486C][2020-01-13T20:06:43]i410: Variable: WixBundleOriginalSource = K:\ServerSetup.exe
[4868:486C][2020-01-13T20:06:43]i410: Variable: WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder = K:\
[4868:486C][2020-01-13T20:06:43]i410: Variable: WixBundleProviderKey = {efdbcc7a-24e7-4b05-a849-1568a9737a42}
[4868:486C][2020-01-13T20:06:43]i410: Variable: WixBundleTag = 
[4868:486C][2020-01-13T20:06:43]i410: Variable: WixBundleVersion = 9.4.7.0
[4868:486C][2020-01-13T20:06:43]i007: Exit code: 0x0, restarting: No
```

Log file for Microsoft R client

```
[4498:5098][2020-01-13T20:24:09]i001: Burn v3.10.1.2213, Windows v10.0 (Build 17763: Service Pack 0), path: D:\360极速浏览器下载\RClientSetup.exe
[4498:5098][2020-01-13T20:24:09]i000: Initializing string variable 'InstallFolder' to value '[ProgramFiles64Folder]Microsoft\R Client'
[4498:5098][2020-01-13T20:24:09]i000: Initializing string variable 'CacheFolder' to value '[TempFolder]'
[4498:5098][2020-01-13T20:24:09]i000: Initializing string variable 'MediaFolder' to value '[TempFolder]'
[4498:5098][2020-01-13T20:24:09]i009: Command Line: ''
[4498:5098][2020-01-13T20:24:09]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'C:\Users\lzw\AppData\Local\Temp\Microsoft_R_Client_20200113202409.log'
[4498:5098][2020-01-13T20:24:09]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value 'D:\360极速浏览器下载\RClientSetup.exe'
[4498:5098][2020-01-13T20:24:09]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder' to value 'D:\360极速浏览器下载\'
[4498:5098][2020-01-13T20:24:09]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleName' to value 'Microsoft R Client'
[4498:5098][2020-01-13T20:24:09]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleManufacturer' to value 'Microsoft'
[4498:5098][2020-01-13T20:24:09]i000: Loading managed bootstrapper application.
[4498:5098][2020-01-13T20:24:09]i000: Creating BA thread to run asynchronously.
[4498:5098][2020-01-13T20:24:09]i500: Shutting down, exit code: 0x0
[4498:5098][2020-01-13T20:24:09]i410: Variable: CacheFolder = C:\Users\lzw\AppData\Local\Temp\
[4498:5098][2020-01-13T20:24:09]i410: Variable: InstallFolder = C:\Program Files\Microsoft\R Client
[4498:5098][2020-01-13T20:24:09]i410: Variable: MediaFolder = C:\Users\lzw\AppData\Local\Temp\
[4498:5098][2020-01-13T20:24:09]i410: Variable: ProgramFiles64Folder = C:\Program Files\
[4498:5098][2020-01-13T20:24:09]i410: Variable: TempFolder = C:\Users\lzw\AppData\Local\Temp\
[4498:5098][2020-01-13T20:24:09]i410: Variable: WixBundleAction = 5
[4498:5098][2020-01-13T20:24:09]i410: Variable: WixBundleElevated = 0
[4498:5098][2020-01-13T20:24:09]i410: Variable: WixBundleLog = C:\Users\lzw\AppData\Local\Temp\Microsoft_R_Client_20200113202409.log
[4498:5098][2020-01-13T20:24:09]i410: Variable: WixBundleManufacturer = Microsoft
[4498:5098][2020-01-13T20:24:09]i410: Variable: WixBundleName = Microsoft R Client
[4498:5098][2020-01-13T20:24:09]i410: Variable: WixBundleOriginalSource = D:\360极速浏览器下载\RClientSetup.exe
[4498:5098][2020-01-13T20:24:09]i410: Variable: WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder = D:\360极速浏览器下载\
[4498:5098][2020-01-13T20:24:09]i410: Variable: WixBundleProviderKey = {4657acfe-78d8-4b9a-bbd6-ef29b555d84e}
[4498:5098][2020-01-13T20:24:09]i410: Variable: WixBundleTag = 
[4498:5098][2020-01-13T20:24:09]i410: Variable: WixBundleVersion = 3.5.2.0
[4498:5098][2020-01-13T20:24:09]i007: Exit code: 0x0, restarting: No
```

Comment: So what error do you get - just "unknown error"? For which component do you get the error; the Machine Learning Server, or the Client?

Comment: Both of them get Unkown error, and both of them let me check the log file.

Comment: Are you installing to the default installation path, or do you change it? And there is nothing in the log file except for what you see above?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using an internet proxy by any chance?

I ran into the same issue. Running the installation script without a proxy solved the issue for me.